# Prime Palindrome Logic Efficiency

Tags: c, palindrome

I wrote a code to get first 1000 prime palindromes ,though my logic is correct ,I dont seem to be getting first 1000 prime palindromes ,I am getting some 113 Prime Palindromes and after that I don't get any . I think this is because my logic is not efficient enough ,that is why it is taking so much time to compile ,but I already tried three different methods and everytime the Runtime is getting stuck after the 113th Prime Palindrome Number .

Can anyone explain why exactly I am getting this problem ,is it because the code is not efficient?

```
/* Program to find the first 1000 prime palindromes */

#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>


int prime(long int n)
{
    int i,check=0;

    if(n!=2 && n%2==0)
        return 0;

    if(n==2 || n==3)
        return 1;

    for(i=3;i<n/2;i=i+2)
        if(n%i==0)
        check++;

    if(check==0)
      return 1;
    else
    return 0;
}

/*long int reverse_number(long int n,long int partial)
{
if(n==0)
    return partial;
else
    return reverse_number(n/10,partial*10 + n%10);
}*/

int palindrome(long int n)
{
    long int reverse = 0;
    long int n_copy = n;
    int rem;
    while(n_copy!=0)
    {
    rem = n_copy%10;
    reverse = reverse*10;
    reverse = reverse + rem;
    n_copy = n_copy/10;
    }

    if(reverse==n)
    return 1;
    else
    return 0;

} 


int main()
{
    long int i;
    int count=5,digits;


    printf("The 1000 prime palindromes are: \n");
    printf("1. 2\n2. 3\n3. 5\n4. 7\n");

    for(i=11;;i=i+2)
    {
        if(prime(i))
        {
            if(palindrome(i))
            {
                printf("%d. %ld\n",count,i);
                count++;
            }
            /*if(reverse_number(i,0)==i)
            {
            printf("%d. %ld\n",count,i);
            count++;

            }*/

        }
        if(count==50)
          break;
    }



    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Not having a chance to look up what the size of these numbers are, but I'd wager that you have an overflow error of some sort. A signed long int is generally 32 bits in C, so you can go up to 2^31-1, or ~2 billion. Anything larger than that will overflow, and could cause unforseen issues.

Comment: i<=√n,  check++ and break

Comment: @Greg No overflow here, prime palindromes aren't that rare. That's what my first suspicion was too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me quote my imperative programming professor here: "You can check whether the number is a prime and a palindrome, or check whether it's a palindrome and a prime..."

Also, you're `break`ing the loop when `count` is 50, which I suppose you want to do when it's 1000.

Without editing the `prime` and `palindrome` functions, besides the order in which they're called, my PC stops finding more after `781 9989899`.

Comment: That's the answer. Also it would make sense to generate palindromes directly (loop from 1 to n and for each number, reverse it and glue the halves together, then repeat with the middle digit removed) and in the primality test it's possible to break out of the loop when a factor is found.

Comment: It doesn't stop, it just becomes slow. The next prime palindrome is 100030001, and since the prime test is Theta(p) for a prime `p`, that takes quite a while to reach.

Comment: Ah yes, it didn't really stop, it's actually still running. (:

Comment: If you don't change the prime test to stop at the square root, it will run a couple of days before finding that one. If you stop at the square root, a couple of seconds till 1000.